# gen file missing/incomplete in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

[image: a picture of my eclipse environment]

can somebody help me fix this?! I cleaned my project and when I tried to use Build it didn't function well, I copied my gen folder from a backup I had. Now this is my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edited your `R.java` manually. You shouldn't do that really. because actually ADT regenerates that file everytime you insert a new string, xml, .. into your directories.

To solve it maybe you can try to delete the file so the ADT will generate it again for you.

And what is that string `Select Image From Gallery` in your file? You should really have any strings in that file! That are names in that file.

And string names cannot contain spaces. That causes an error when compiler tries to compile the java file.

If you want to add a string you can go to the `values/strings.xml` and add the string there. and adt will update the `R.java` automatically!

Comment: sure, but since last time was not that much successful, can you lead me to do it correctly this time? what should I do exactly?

Comment: @Shawn do what? create new string?

Comment: to delete the gen file and build the project again. I did it now, I deleted gen file and right click on the project, then click on build, it regenerated the gen file but it was just the same. The error was there again!!!!

Comment: @Shawn are you cleaning your Console Log before you build again!? Maybe it's the errors from your last compiles. And the error is solved now. The thing is that eclipse doesn't clean the errors in the log when you solve them..

Comment: @Shawn to clean, click on the first icon from the left on the console log and it will clean. It's like a document with an X on it.

Comment: yeah, I just tried what you asked me to do, once I build it, it says:

 'R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!'

Comment: @Shawn is that an error? It doesn't seem to be. It just informs you that it has generated a new file. I think you can just ignore it. BTW can you please get a new screen shot from this new message?

Comment: Yes it is, it actually is containing the same error as before and it doesn't let me compile my application. I updated the question with the new screen shot, but trust me, it is the same! ;)

Comment: @Shawn Oh got what the problem is! :D go to your values/strings.xml and in the string that is `Select Image From Gallery` . The string names cannot contain spaces! That makes java compiler and xml parser upset :-p use underscores instead of spaces and your problem will be solved!

Comment: Bingo!
I knew it was a tiny problem!
You are simply a genius Man, I appreciate it. I wish I could give you 100+ votes.
Thanks again, You made my day! ;)

Comment: @Shawn you're welcome. I'm happy that I helped you solve it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your R file. Delete the gen folder. Right Click On your Project and Build Your Project.

If there is no problems in your code ,your project should build properly.

Remember never manually edit your R file.

Comment: thanks, but the thing is last time I did it, but when Build it, it didn't work! nothing happened. I know it sounds stupid, but that made my crazy!

Comment: Have you deleted the gen folder and build your project again.If yes and you are still getting the issue.Check are there any errors in your code or have your java file imported the android.R ,if yes remove this import

Comment: Yes I did it and the errors are just the ones before (when there's no R.java, the application has no problem, but when there is, any changes that I make, it says: 'R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!' or 'R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!'
I don't wanna sound stupid, but this thing is killing me right now!

Comment: You should not modify your R.java file .It is a system generated file and System does not allow you to edit it.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But what am I supposed to do now? Deleting gen file and reBuild the application didn't work!

Comment: It means your code has some error, try to figure it out and correct it.Then Build your project,it shall build